# Efficient way to aggregate a table only considering items that have a particular entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry for the clunky title. An example will explain.

Say I have a likes table, with an entry for each like

```
user_id  |  liked_id
--------------------
   1     |     a
   2     |     a
   1     |     b
   2     |     c
```

Meaning user `1` has liked items `a` and `b`, and user `2` has liked items `a` and `c`.

To get an aggregate count of likes for each item, I can do:

```
SELECT liked_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM likes
  GROUP BY liked_id
```

Is there a nice way, however, to do that but *only* for items that have been liked by a particular user? So, for instance, querying on user `1`, the result I'd like is:

```
liked_id |  count
------------------
   a     |    2
   b     |    1
```

Because user `1` has liked items `a` and `b`, but not `c`.

The best I can think of is a `JOIN` or `IN` with a subselect:

```
SELECT l.liked_id, count(*)
  FROM likes l
    JOIN (
      SELECT liked_id
        FROM likes
        WHERE user_id = 1
      ) l2
      ON l.liked_id=l2.liked_id
  GROUP BY l.liked_id;
```

Is there a better way to roll things up when aggregating? I feel  like there might be some `HAVING` trickery I can do, but maybe not and it might be a slower solution anyway.

EDIT: I am using Postgres, if the tags did not make that clear.

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers, I accepted what I thought was the best and fastest, as I asked the question - should've been obvious, really, but I gave everyone a +1.

I should've mentioned that I needed another piece of data from the entry in the likes table so I can order on that later. The subselect will do it as will the accepted answers self join with an additional entry in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` parts. That'll teach me to oversimplify something for a SO question... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: Join the table to itself:

```
SELECT t1.liked_id, COUNT(*)
FROM likes t1
JOIN likes t2 on t2.liked_id = t1.liked_id
WHERE t1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY t1.liked_id
```

Not only is this an elegant way to code it, it is also the best performing, as long as there is an index on `liked_id` for join perfomance, and an index on `user_id` for lookup performance.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't come up with this in the first place... it's good because I can also get other information from the row in `likes` of the given user (e.g. `SELECT ..., t1.timestmp ... GROUP BY t1.liked_id, t1.timestmp;`) which is in fact something I need to do for ordering later (this is part of a larger query). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT liked_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM likes
 GROUP BY liked_id
HAVING count(case when user_id = 1 then 1 end) > 0;
```

`count(case when user_id = 1 then 1 end)` will count how many times `user_id = 1` liked particular `liked_id`.

This query will get the results in one full scan. It will be faster than 2 full scans, but might be slower than 2 index scans (if you have indexes on `liked_id` and `user_id`).

Answer (score 1):

Use [EXISTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html)

```
SELECT  L.LIKED_ID
        ,COUNT(L.USER_ID) AS USER_COUNT
FROM    LIKES L
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT  1 
                FROM    LIKES L2 
                WHERE   L2.LIKED_ID = L.LIKED_ID 
                AND L2.USER_ID = 1
                )
GROUP BY 
        L.LIKED_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, as per my understanding, you need to get the `count` of liked items that have only been liked by a particular `user`

```
SELECT 
  liked_id, 
  COUNT(*)
FROM 
  likes l
WHERE
  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM likes WHERE user_id = 1 AND like_id = l.id )
GROUP BY 
  liked_id
```